# Удалить из строковой переменной все кроме HEX символов и символа # (регистронезависимая реализация)

Tags: php

Нужна php функция.
Оставить после обработки строки только следующие символы:

```
ABCDEFabcdef0123456789#
```

Comment: $test = preg_replace("/[^A-Fa-f0-9#]/", '', $test);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$test = preg_replace("/[^A-Fa-f0-9#]/", '', $test);
```

Comment: Хотя, вы в вопросе символы перепутали местами.